# Form not submitting when JavaScript validated

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form with a dropdown that gets validated, the validation works fine but form won't submit if user selects any option other than the default.

I created a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36JZL/41/)** of the current code in an easier to read format.

Why isn't my form submitting?

**JavaScript**

```
$('#btncheck').click(function () {
    if ($("#mySelect ")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
        alert("Please select a tank from the menu!");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a `return true` statement above `form.submit();` You need to switch the order of these.

```
$('#btncheck').click(function(){
    if ($("#mySelect")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
         alert("Please select a tank from the menu!");
         return false;
    }
    form.submit(); 
    return true;
});
```

(I've also cleaned up your code a little.)

---

I've edited your JSFiddle, and come up with a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/36JZL/44/ You can see that the part of the code that submits the form is being reached when the alert box pops up.

---

To answer your last comment, I've updated the JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/36JZL/46/. This changes the background color of the drop-down and gives an error message beneath it.

Comment: i did this but the form still wont submit?? no errors or nothing happening

Comment: OK, see my revised post. I linked you to a new JSFiddle. Notice that I gave your form an ID to make it easier to submit.

Comment: instead of popup alert can i make the dropdown styled with .css glow red? and give red text on the page if fail valid select on dropdown? saying "please select a tank from the menu!"

Comment: can i assign it a css attribute from my stylesheet instead of inline style in the JavaScript?

Comment: Sure, you just use the `addClass` jQuery method.

Answer (score 4):

Anything after `return` won't fire:

```
return true;
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
$('#btncheck').click(function(){
     if ($("#mySelect ")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
         alert("Please select a tank from the menu!");
                return false;
                }
    else {
        //return true;
        $('form').submit(); 
    }
});
});
```

p.s. add action tag (e.g. action='server-side.php') in form, otherwise form will be submitted/processed to/on same page (maybe you want it, don't know) and method (i guess that you don't want default - GET)

Answer (score 0):

Return is the end point of any function !

Anything placed after return won't execute.

I suggest you use a step by step debugger with breakpoints, here's a guide for chrome dev tools
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging